# plated through hole file?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, gerber, ultiboard

I'm designing a new product and my manufacturer can't continue with out a "plated through hole file". They say that I didn't put it in the gerber files.
How do I generate this in ultiboard? Or any where else?

Comment: Have you tried Ultiboard support?

Comment: indeed, nothing that helps

Comment: You should ask the PCB vendor what they mean. Most vendors plate all holes by default, and specify how to denote non-plated holes if you need them.

Comment: I have never heard of a "plated through hole file" before. So far, every PCB vendor I've used, and that has been quite a few, automatically plate holes that have any copper going to them on any layer. There has never been a need for a separate file. The only question is what to do with holes that have no copper going to them. That depends on their process. Most will not plate them, but some, like Advanced Circuits' prototype process, cause all holes to be plated.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: I bet he means the Excellon drill file. Almog, this file often has to be generated outside your Gerbers. If you define holes for your PCB, next to the diameter you'll also have to say whether it has to be plated.

Comment: @almog: Ask Ultiboard support about the Excellon drill file. If they can't help you with that, ask a refund for the package and buy a decent EDA package.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing based on little information, but here's what I would think if knowing only what you posted:
What they mean is probably an Excellon drill file for the holes that need to be plated.
The fab needs to drill these holes before plating, which is different from the holes/slots/cutouts made at the end of the manufacturing process.
It may also be that this file is included, but the board fab for some reason thinks it's a post-plating file rather than pre-plating.